# awk list of files - output print only one line per inputfile

Tags: awk

I want to extract data from a list of input files.
I need $1 if string contains "Date" and $4, $5, $6 and $7 if field $3 is "Sum". Input is tab delimited.
input1.txt

```
Bla-1                       
Bla-2                       
Bla-3                       
Report                      
Date 2016.01.04                     
Blub-a                      
Blub-b                      
Blub-c                      
Blub-n                      
    text    text    amount  fee fee2    transit
        bluber  50  5   1   
        blubber 40  4   1   
        blubbest    10  1   1   
        Sum 100 10  3   87
```

input2.txt

```
Bla-1                       
Bla-2                       
Bla-3                       
Report                      
Date 2016.01.11                     
Blub-1                      
Blub-2                      
Blub-3                      
Blub-n                      
    text    text    amount  fee fee2    transit
        bluber  50  5   1   
        blubber 40  4   1   
        blubbest    10  1   1   
        Sum 200 10  10  180
```

my output is:

```
Date     Sum     Sum of Fee      Transit
2016.01.04          
2016.01.04          
2016.01.04          
2016.01.04          
2016.01.04          
2016.01.04          
2016.01.04          
2016.01.04          
2016.01.04          
2016.01.04  100 13  87
2016.01.11  100 13  87
2016.01.11  100 13  87
2016.01.11  100 13  87
2016.01.11  100 13  87
2016.01.11  100 13  87
2016.01.11  100 13  87
2016.01.11  100 13  87
2016.01.11  100 13  87
2016.01.11  100 13  87
2016.01.11  200 23  177
```

My desired output is:

```
Date     Sum     Sum of Fee      Transit
2016.01.04  100 13  87
2016.01.11  200 23  177
```

My awk has to go through hundreds of input*.txt and I only want to extract the information given in the desired output for each input file. AWK:

```
BEGIN { FS="\t"; OFS="\t";
print "Date \t Sum \t Sum of Fee \t Transit"
}

FNR==1    {flag=0}
{
if ($1~/Date/) {$1=substr($1,6,11); date=$1};
if ($3~/Sum/)  {amount=$4; fee=$5+$6; transit=$7};
}

flag!=0 {print date OFS amount OFS fee OFS transit};
/Report/ {flag=1}
```

Comment: Not clear, please add more details in your question about your request and let us know then.

Comment: Why would the last 2 fields of desired output be `23  177` instead of `20 180`?

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS="\t"
    print "Date", "Sum", "Sum of Fee", "Transit"
}
sub(/^Date /,"",$1) { date = $1 }
$3=="Sum" { print date, $4, $5+$6, $7 }
' input*.txt
Date    Sum     Sum of Fee      Transit
2016.01.04      100     13      87
2016.01.11      200     20      180
```